# How can I dynamically change title in Vite React?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Vite React template has a file called `index.html` at the root of the project.

The way I understood, this file is static.

I want to change the title of each page based individually.

I know I can use `useEffect` in each page and set the title using simple vanilla JS.

But I wonder if there is a better more standard react-y way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) package, it enables you to add head tag in any component that you want

Answer (score 1):

Using `useEffect` seems pretty reasonable. You can encapsulate it into your own `useTitle` hook for more clarity (see for instance https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-title).